# Como reordenar datos de una pagina en php al pulsar un texto/enlace html

Tags: php, html

Tengo una lista de productos de una tabla que rescato en php pasándole un orden a la consulta

```
function getProductos($orden) {
        $link = crearConexion();
                $query = "select product.id, product.name, product.cost, product.price, category.name as tipo_producto from product inner join category on product.category_id = category.id order by " . $orden . ";";
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    return $result;
                }else{
                    echo "No se encontraron los productos";
                    return null; 
                }
                cerrarConexion($link);
    }
```

Luego tengo la función que muestra los productos en la pagina. EL caso es que tengo que conseguir que los productos se reordenen al clickar en los títulos de la tabla según lo que hayas clickado

```
function pintaProductos($orden) {
            $data = getProductos($orden);
            
            if(comprobarPermisos()){
                echo "<table> 
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Coste</th>
                                <th>Precio</th>
                                <th>Categoria</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
                    echo "<tr>\n
                                <td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>\n
                                <td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>\n
                                <td>" . $row["cost"] . "</td>\n
                                <td>" . $row["price"] . "</td>\n
                                <td>" . $row["tipo_producto"] . "</td>\n
                                <td>" . "<a href='formArticulos.php'>Editar</a>"
                            . "- <a href='formArticulos.php'>Borrar</a>" . "</td>\n
                              </tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                            
            }else{
                echo "<table> 
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Coste</th>
                                <th>Precio</th>
                                <th>Categoria</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
                    echo "<tr>\n
                                <td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>\n
                                <td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>\n
                                <td>" . $row["cost"] . "</td>\n
                                <td>" . $row["price"] . "</td>\n
                                <td>" . $row["tipo_producto"] . "</td>\n
                              </tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }
            
    }
```

Como puedo conseguir sacar los datos de evento solo usando php y html sin incluir ajax ni js? Usando un en enlace html?

[image: Pagina que se genera con la funciones]

Comment: Te iba a sugerir DataTables pero como dices que nada de nada mas que PHP y HTML, se me ocurre que cada header de tu tabla sea un link que te lleve a un archivo con la info ordenada según el link presionado...

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla, y básica, sería enviando una instrucción via GET para que el script sepa con qué criterio debe ordenar.

Se puede usar una url con la siguiente estructura. Si no se especifica el orden o si se coloca un dato no válido, PHP usará uno por defecto.

```
http[s]://la_dirección.com/la_pagina.php?orden=precio
```

Ahora en el archivo `la_pagina.php`:

```php
// ...
$ord_opts = ['id'=>'product.id', 'nombre'=>'product.name', 
    'coste'=>'product.cost', 'precio'=>'product.price', 'categoria'=>'category.name'];

if(isset($_GET['orden']) and array_key_exists($_GET['orden'], $ord_opts)) {
    $orden = $ord_opts[$_GET['orden']];
} else {
    $orden = 'product.id'; // <-- El orden por defecto
}

// ... La consulta permanece igual

$query = "select product.id, product.name, product.cost, 
product.price, category.name as tipo_producto 
from product 
inner join category on product.category_id = category.id 
order by " . $orden . ";";
// ...
```

Finalmente, en la parte donde se muestran los datos, le agregas un vínculo a las cabeceras de la tabla para enviarle las órdenes GET al mismo script:

```html
    <tr>
        <th><a href="la_pagina.php?orden=id">ID</a></th>
        <th><a href="la_pagina.php?orden=nombre">Nombre</a></th>
        <th><a href="la_pagina.php?orden=coste">Coste</a></th>
        <th><a href="la_pagina.php?orden=precio">Precio</a></th>
        <th><a href="la_pagina.php?orden=categoria">Categoria</a></th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>";
```